# replace values of numerical attribute in rapidminer by condition

Tags: rapidminer

how can I replace values of a numerical attribute in rapidminer by condition?
for example:
I have an age attribute and I want to set any data above 80 to 80.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Generate Attributes` operator and the `if()` function. For example, if your attribute is called `age` then you would set `age` as the attribute name and `if(age > 80, 80, age)` as the value.